# In Ionic, how can I have 10 tabs as main navigation but only show 4 and a "More" button which shows the rest in a list?

Tags: ionic-framework

I use Ionic Framework and I'm using tabs as main navigation. I have the following HTML

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

<!-- Home Tab -->
<ion-tab title="Home" icon-off="ion-ios-home-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-home" href="#/tab/home">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-home"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<!-- what if I want to add 9 more tabs here? -->

</ion-tabs>
```

What if I want to have 10 tabs? Then I want the default iOS behaviour, which is to show 4 first tabs, a "More" tab, which upon click, shows the rest of the tabs in a list.

Is this possible in ionic?

Comment: As an FYI, I filed an ER for this: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4320

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, not possible be default. One could either write a plugin to add this functionality, but the framework it self does not have it baked in.